# android query for phone number without format

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contacts

I'm trying to get all the contacts which has number that starts with some query.

```
contactLookup = getContentResolver().query(
                Data.CONTENT_URI,
            new String[] { Data._ID, Phone.NUMBER, Phone.TYPE, Phone.LABEL },
            Data.MIMETYPE + "='" + Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "' and "
                    + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER + " like ?",
            new String[] { "%" + query + "%" }, null);

if (contactLookup != null && contactLookup.getCount() > 0) { 
   contactLookup.moveToNext();
   String number = contactLookup.getString(contactLookup.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
   Log.v("debug", number);
   contactLookup.getString(contactLookup.getColumnIndex(BaseColumns._ID));
}
```

The number is 123-456-789 but my query string is 123456. How do i compare only number without formatting characters.

Answer (score 0):

Look at what is available in PhoneUtils in the SDK.